# Change colour of a filled text box when it loses focus

Tags: jquery, css

I want to change the color of a text filled when it is filled and loses focus. The form I have created asks for at least one field to be filled.

I have tried `:required`, `:valid` but that change the color of all the fields

```html
<form action="h.php" method="post" onsubmit="return formcheck()">
    <div class="least1">
        <label for="cb1">MAKAUT Development Fees:</label>
        <input type="text" name="cb1" value="" placeholder="0"><br>
    </div>
    <div class="least1">
        <label for="cb2">MAKAUT Registration Fees:</label>
        <input type="text" name="cb2" value="" placeholder="0"><br>
    </div>
    <button>Submit</button>
</form>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function formcheck(){
        var total=0;
        var fields = $(".least1")
        .find("input").serializeArray();
        $.each(fields, function(i, field) {
            if (field.value!="")
                total=total+parseInt(field.value);
        }); 
        // console.log(fields);
        if(total==0){
            alert("Fill at least one field.");
            return false;
        }
        else{
            if(confirm("Total amount to be paid= "+total))
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
    }
    jQuery(function ($) {
        var $inputs = $('input[name=cb1],input[name=cb2]');
        $inputs.on('input', function () {
            // Set the required property of the other input to false if this input is not empty.
            $inputs.not(this).prop('required', !$(this).val().length);
            $inputs.css({
                "border-color": "red", 
                "font-weight": "bold"
            }) ;
        });
    });

</script>
```

All field change color instead of one.

Comment: bind something to `blur` or `focusout` events?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have a placeholder present, you could use this:

```
.myInput:not(:placeholder-shown):not(:focus) { /* change stuff */ }
```

If the form has no value, the placeholder will be shown.
So if it **has a value / user has input some data** (aka the :placeholder-shown is not true) and it **loses focus** (aka the :focus is not true) - the style will be applied.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on("focusout","input",function(){
 if($(this).prop('required'))
   if(!$(this).val())
    {
     $(this).css({
            "border-color": "red", 
            "font-weight": "bold"
        }) ;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I just update your method with focusout method. Try this I hope it'll help you out. Thanks

```
$("input[name=cb1],input[name=cb2]").focusout(function(){
   $(this).css({"border-color": "red", "font-weight": "bold"});
});
```

> **Focusout Method Example -** [Link](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_focusout.asp)

```html
<form action="h.php" method="post" onsubmit="return formcheck()">
    <div class="least1">
        <label for="cb1">MAKAUT Development Fees:</label>
        <input type="text" name="cb1" value="" placeholder="0"><br>
    </div>
    <div class="least1">
        <label for="cb2">MAKAUT Registration Fees:</label>
        <input type="text" name="cb2" value="" placeholder="0"><br>
    </div>
    <button>Submit</button>
</form>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function formcheck(){
        var total=0;
        var fields = $(".least1")
        .find("input").serializeArray();
        $.each(fields, function(i, field) {
            if (field.value!="")
                total=total+parseInt(field.value);
        }); 
        // console.log(fields);
        if(total==0){
            alert("Fill at least one field.");
            return false;
        }
        else{
            if(confirm("Total amount to be paid= "+total))
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
    }
    $("input[name=cb1],input[name=cb2]").focusout(function(){
      $(this).css({"border-color": "red", "font-weight": "bold"});
    });

</script>
```